# Yii 2: Unable to create a relation with a condition about the related table

Tags: php, yii2

Simplifing, I've two tables:

```
Product: id, name
Datasheet: id, product_id
```

Where `product_id` points to `products.id`. Each Product could have 0 or 1 Datasheet.

Into my `Product` class (wich extends `ActiveQuery`) I've created this relation

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getDatasheet()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Datasheet::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I'm able now to query in this way

```
$products_without_datasheet = Product::find()
        ->with('datasheet')
        ->all();
```

What I really need is to retrieve **only** the products **without** the datasheet.

I'd like to create a 'scope' (like in yii 1) to be able to reuse the resulting condition `datasheet.id IS NULL` because this situation has a lot of variants and will be used all around the app.

I'm not able to understand how to create a relation with an added filter, something like `getWithoutDatasheet()` to be used as

```
Product::find()->with('withoutDatasheet')->all();
```

or

```
Product::find()->withoutDatasheet()->all();
```

Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create ActiveQuery for Product. See how gii generated ActiveRecord with ActiveQuery.

In Product:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return ProductQuery the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    return new ProductQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

In ProductQuery:

```
public function withoutDatasheet()
{
    $this->with('datasheet');

    return $this;
}
```

Usage:

```
Product::find()->withoutDatasheet()->all();
```

Comment: What about the comment row `    //Join Datasheet and see products without datasheets.` ? It's exactly my problem... how to do this?

Comment: and how to remove rows with datasheet.id NULL? I tried adding `$this->andWhere(['datasheet.id'=> null]);` but Yii2 warn me that datasheet.is doesn't exists. Yes... the table is tbl_datasheet.... why don't he add the prefix automaticaly?

Comment: ActiveQuery should have full path to table with prefixes, and sometimes even database. This [SQL hint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ5XP.png) will be helpful for understanding.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question is why don't Yii add it automatically?

Comment: Yii don't know how. ActiveQuery is simple cover under sql. However you have `$this->modelClass` in ActiveQuery. It may be helpful for determine that `tableName` need to use.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only the products without the datasheet you can do it like this:

```
$productsWithDatasheet = Datasheet::find()
    ->select('product_id')
    ->distinct()
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

$productIdsWithDatasheet = ArrayHelper::getColumn($productsWithDatasheet, 'product_id');

$productsWithoutDatasheet = Product::find()
    ->where(['not in', 'id', $productIdsWithDatasheet ])
    ->all();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I asked how to do using ActiveRecord and/or ActiveQuery classes